# Why do backticks not work inside HTML lists?

Tags: support, code-formatting, markdown, markdown-rendering

Often I want to include inline code inside a list:

1. Why isn’t `this` working ?

Actually, the code block does appear, but when you write the ending `</ol>` tag, then the formatting disappears.

See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/30961731/4759361

Comment: Interesting behavior. Delete the `<ol>` and replace the first `<li>` with `1.`, and the rest of the list magically adjusts itself. Must be a weird interaction between MD and raw HTML copying.

Comment: AFAIK it's intentional that many html tags disable markdown within them. but I don't remember which tags.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This is correct Markdown behavior. As the [syntax rules](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html) state:

> Note that Markdown formatting syntax is not processed within block-level HTML tags. E.g., you can’t use Markdown-style `*emphasis*` inside an HTML block.

If you want to use raw HTML blocks, then use **all** raw HTML within that block. Of course, this gets confusing because some Markdown parsers deviate from the rules and allow some exceptions to that rule. However, when I'm writing Markdown, I always follow the strictest set of rules and then I'm never surprised.

Answer (score 22):

Your should use Markdown for lists and as much other layout you can.

That works:

1. `yes`!

Which is:

```
1. `yes`!
```

Comment: Yeah, but I’m pretty comfortable with html so that makes me feel better. html should work, right? Markdown is an alternative.

Comment: No. Markdown is the standard used here. HTML is secondary.

Comment: Oh okay, then I’ll have to pick up Markdown. But this is still a bug, right? Or is this behaviour intentional?

Comment: Not sure. I just think they agreed that HTML should do something different than you expected.

Comment: I guess when the parser reaches some HTML, and decides it's one of the tags that it's not going to throw away, then it just stops parsing it for further markdown so that it doesn't interrupt what the user may have intended.

Comment: Not a bug, how else could one make sure embedded html actually works?

Answer (score 20):

As an alternative to switching to Markdown, you can use the `<code></code>` tag. This works inside of an HTML list:

1. `this is code`

In other words, you can opt to use markdown or HTML, but the mixture of the two occasionally causes problems.